# How to list all called function in a php file using netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans, ide

I want to list function names which I've `called` in a particular `PHP` file using netbeans. In navigator I'm able to see list of functions which I've have definition in that file and including constants.

Is there way to list all functions which are defined in other PHP files and `called` in my intended file ?

Edit:

Project was written using `POP` concepts and I'm looking for a solution as `navigator` works in-case of defined functions and constants in same file.

Answer (score 0):

I see two small solutions :

1. Use PHP's namespace on each file and then in netbeans when you start to type the name of a namespace, it will display every function inside with the autocomplete.
2. Create a main PHP file listing every PHP function like a summary. Inside this file each function call the function of another file... problably too late to setup something like this I guess.

Hope it will bring you ideas...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Project is written in `POP` and due to time constraints can't even have chance to do changes which you have suggested. Anyhow thanks.

Comment: Yeah that's what I guessed, you probably far in your project and change one thing would probably display a huge amount of errors. Personally I use both technics I listed. Each of my class PHP file got a namespace and I have  a main summary call "application", when I type "application" in Netbeans, it displays every functions I listed. Then it's my "application" file wich calls function in external files. Like that I'm not typing "class1", "class2", etc. and need to remember every namespace, I just type "application" and it makes the work for me.